# How to save 'Array of images as burst-shot images in photo library' in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, save, avfoundation, avcapture

"I'm trying to create burst-shot feature in my camera app, and want to save burst-shot images to photo library. Until now I'm having array of images by long pressing the capture button?"